# In iOS 7, layoutSubviews method is called constantly on UIButton subclass

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uibutton, ios7

I have a subclass of UIButton on a view. Works great in iOS 6, 5, etc. But in iOS 7, I'm noticing delays when I try to change the title (using setTitle:forState:).  I've tracked down the issue to the fact that the foundation is constantly calling layoutSubviews on my control, and this causing the CPU usage to hover around 100% for the lifetime of the app.

In my subclass, I overrode layoutSubviews and added a breakpoint to diagnose the problem.  The backtrace only shows the method called from the [UIView layoutSublayersOfLayer] method in the foundation.

Note that if I comment out this line:

`[super layoutSubviews];`

the CPU problem goes away, but, of course, other problems arise.

Has anyone seen this?  Why is iOS 7 calling layoutSubviews constantly?

Comment: Can you provide some code?  Typically you would only call that method because you are subclassing `layoutSubviews`.  If you need to force a layout, you generally would use `setNeedsLayout` to avoid multiple layout calls, so there could be something fishy elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks, Brian.  I only subclassed layoutSubviews to diagnose the CPU pegging at 100%.  When I comment out the method, the problem doesn't go away.

Comment: In the same vein, I also tried subclassing setNeedsLayout, and found (with a breakpoint) that it was being called from [UIButton _beginTitleAnimation] (a private method).  I would be content in disabling animations for the button, but I don't know of a way to do that.

Comment: That doesn't explain why you would be seing `layoutSubviews` called a lot.  An animation would only call it once.  When you look in Instruments, do you see anywhere where `layoutSubviews` recursing a lot (maybe triggering a method in your class and then back)?  There's no way to answer this without the code.

Comment: Too much code to pare down.  Answered below.

Comment: For anyone else with 100% cpu on an infinite loop within layoutsubviews, The same issue occurs with an empty layoutSubviews override.

Answer (score 5):

Found the problem. In my setEnabled: method (part of the reason for the subclass in the first place), I had the following line:

```
self.titleLabel.alpha = enabled ? 1.0 : 0.8;
```

And apparently in iOS 7, this causes UIButton to begin a title-change animation that it never finishes.  The result is an infinite loop in which layoutSubviews is repeatedly called.

The fix was to include this line when the titleColor is changed:

```
[self setTitleColor:[[self titleColorForState:UIControlStateNormal] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.8] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

And the infinite loop is averted!