# iOS 7 UITextView - layoutSubviews infinite loop

Tags: ios7, uitextview, autolayout, layoutsubviews

I have UITextView:

```
textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

I have a problem only on iOS7:

On every keyboard keystroke, `layoutSubviews` is called on superview. After writing several characters, it gets stuck in infinite loop and keeps calling `layoutSubviews` constantly.

When I remove `textView.scrollEnabled = NO;` line of code, everything works the way it is supposed to.

I would really like to disable scrolling on my text view. Does anybody have an idea how to do it?

Comment: are you overriding layoutSubviews in your class?

Comment: No. I only overriden it to prove my suspicion and delegated the call to super.

This problem is most probably related to this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18991001/in-ios-7-layoutsubviews-method-is-called-constantly-on-uibutton-subclass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I hacked the whole thing by placing a Pan Gesture on UITextView. This way all functionalities of editing text view were preserved and scrolling was disabled.
When I wanted to disable scrolling of text view, I didn't set `scrollEnabled = NO`. Instead I added Pan Gesture recognizer on UITextView. When I wanted to enable scrolling, I just removed that same Pan Gesture recognizer from text view.

Like this:

init method...

```
    _scrollDisablerGR = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(textViewScrollAction:)];
// method textViewScrollAction does nothing, empty implementation
    [_textView addGestureRecognizer:_scrollDisablerGR];
```

somewhere else in code:

```
if (shouldEnableScrolling) {
        [self.textView removeGestureRecognizer:_scrollDisablerGR];
    } else {
        if (!_scrollDisablerGR.view) {
            [self.textView addGestureRecognizer:_scrollDisablerGR];
        }
    }
```

Works great ;)